Filename starting with .(dot) does not appear in Azure Devops pipeline
So I have one Azure Repository Where I using SQLfluff for SQL linting.

As You can see, I am using a property file .sqlfluff, It is available in git.
In Azure devops pipeline, I am using following command to checkout the files for validation purpose.
 - checkout: self
      displayName: 'Checkout & Build.Reason: $(Build.Reason) & Build.SourceBranchName: $(Build.SourceBranchName) & System.PullRequest.TargetBranch: $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)'
      persistCredentials: true
      clean: true
      fetchDepth: 0

Other files are getting successfully copied to "(Build.SourcesDirectory)" except the file .sqlfluff.

I have tried multiple. Every files that have name starting with (.) is getting ignored. Where as other files are working fine.
Please let me know the solution.

It is probably there, just hidden away. On *nix systems, files starting with a dot are hidden files, now shown by default. Read the manual of the (undisclosed) tool you use to list files, and see how to also display hidden files (probably -a).

I can reproduce your issue when using tree command in ubuntu image. The tree command in Unix-like operating systems doesn’t show files or directories that start with a . by default because these are considered hidden.
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'tree'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'


To show the hidden files, you can use find command or add -a to tree command as mentioned by @YSC.

Use find


Use tree -a



